# how to remove first 3 word in the sentence In javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, api

How can I remove the first three words in java script  when the response from the api I want to delete or remove the first three words.. the message from api is like below

"Error: GraphQL error: Account code already taken "

```
var temp = e.message
var temp1 = temp.map(function(f) {
  return f.substring(temp.indexOf(' ') + 2);
});
console.log("Output", temp1)
```

expected output  : " Account code already taken"

Comment: Doesn't the OP actually want to take everything after the second colon/`:` which might the most generic treatment for the error messages, instead of what was asked for in the first place?

Comment: @MikeM I already tried this but doesn't work replace function

Comment: [`'Error: GraphQL error: Account code already taken'.replace((/^(?:[^:]+:\s*){1,2}/), '')`](https://regex101.com/r/jvpYJn/1)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var st = "Error: GraphQL error: Account code already taken."   
var s = st.split(' ')
s.splice(0,3)
st = s.join(' ');
console.log("Output", st)
```

Try this code

Comment: but the problem is that dynamic message is appear from the api instead of ""Error: GraphQL error:  " it can be " GraphQL error"

Comment: Should I always remove the first 3 words?

Comment: message is dynamic should not appear the two words " graphql and error " wouldn't fixed the index probably the message will remove

Comment: @khawarshah ... Since your changed requirements do not anymore reflect the original question in its current topic and content, please update your question to what you really want, by providing additional examples to different input data and each of its expected result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the certain word like *error:* is present in the message then you can split the string with the word and return string from specific index:

```js
var temp = "Error: GraphQL error: Account code already taken "
var temp1 = function(f) {
  if(f.split('error:').length > 1)
    return f.split('error:')[1].trim();
  else return f;
};
console.log("Output:", temp1(temp))
```

**Update:** First, I will suggest you to fix the message format if possible. If you have to possible situation where the word in the message could be either *error* or *error:* then you can try the following:

```js
var temp = "Error: GraphQL error Account code already taken "
var temp1 = function(f) {
  var splitVal = 'error';
  if(f.includes('error:'))
    splitVal = 'error:';
  if(f.split(splitVal).length > 1)
    return f.split(splitVal)[1].trim();
  else return f;
};
console.log("Output:", temp1(temp));
```

Comment: Thankyou guys for your answering but I don't want to fixed the index  .. because the messages are dynamic . if ``` graphql and error``` two word're exist in the message . only remove this

Comment: @khawarshah ... this last comment of your's changes the task entirely. Please update/edit your question according to your new acceptance criteria.

Comment: @khawarshah ... new solution on your updated matter ... [`'Error: GraphQL error:   Account code already taken'.replace((/\s*graphql\s+error\s*:*\s*/i), ' ')`](https://regex101.com/r/jvpYJn/2)

Comment: @khawarshah, I have updated the answer with another solution. You can try that. You can also try the solution provided in the above comment by *PeterSeliger*....

Answer (score 0):

Create/modify the function to remove one word:

```
function removeOne(f) {
  return f.substring(f.indexOf(' ') + 1);
}
```

and call it 3 times:

```
var temp1 = removeOne(removeOne(removeOne(temp)));
```

or in a loop:

```
var temp1 = temp;
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  temp1 = removeOne(temp1);
}
```

EDIT: wrapped the post into a snippet if someone had doubts:

```js
var temp = "Error: GraphQL error: Account code already taken ";

/* Create/modify the function to remove one word: */
function removeOne(f) {
  return f.substring(f.indexOf(' ') + 1);
}

/*and call it 3 times:*/
var temp1 = removeOne(removeOne(removeOne(temp)));
console.log("Output", temp1);

/*or in a loop:*/
temp1 = temp;
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  temp1 = removeOne(temp1);
}
console.log("Output", temp1);
```

Answer (score -1):

const shorten = () => input.slice(21, input.length)